# .htaccess > redirect all subfolders to root (ignore trailing slash)

Tags: .htaccess

My gosh - I hate .htaccess ... and don't understand how the hell anything is working.
I am trying to ignore 'subfolders' and use these as guest identifyer.
Ex:

`User types > http://subdomain.domain.com/guest_id`

`Server sends > http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php`

`Browser shows > http://subdomain.domain.com/guest_id`

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [NC]
```

The code works great... unless there is a trailing slash.
In this case, all files are served as 'index.php'.
The main Index.php is showing properly, but all external scripts / css / etc. are served as /guest_id/index.php (thus... do not load).

FYI, there might be a conflict as my 'subdomain' is actually invisibly serving domain.com/event/

I have been trying so many permutations... without really understanding how htaccess work.

Your help will be sooooo much appreciated.
1,000 thanks in advance!
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have URL such as `http://subdomain.domain.com/guest_id/` and are using **relative links** for your css/js/images then browser attempts to resolve all links by prefixing them with current path hence `src='image.png'` is resolved as `http://subdomain.domain.com/guest_id/image.png` instead of `http://subdomain.domain.com/image.png`.

You can have a rule to force remove trailing slash at the end of all non-directory URLs.

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.